# What can I do to list activities instead of package name in my code?

Tags: android

I am using the following code to list all installed activities but instead of showing the app name it shows the name like com.xyz.xyz.dialer
I want it to show app name only. Where do I need to change and to what?

```
public class AppPicker extends ListActivity{

// Buffer used to store package and class information, and also determine the number of installed activities
private ArrayList<String[]> _activitiesBuffer = null;

// Buffers for package and class information
private String[] _packages = null;
private String[] _classes = null;

// Index used to fill buffers
private int _index = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get all installed activities (package and class information for every activity)
    getAllInstalledActivities();              

    // Set content to GUI
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, _classes));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    // Add listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // When clicked, show a toast with the selected activity
            Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(), 
                ((TextView) view).getText(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // When clicked, start selected activity, if allowed or possible
            try {

                Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(
                        _packages[position], // package 
                        _classes[position]); // class
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

      } // public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

    });

} // public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

This is the getInstalledActivities method. I have seperated it here for easy access.

```
   /*
 * Get all installed activities
 */
private void getAllInstalledActivities() {

    // Initialize activities buffer
    _activitiesBuffer = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0);

    Iterator<ResolveInfo> iterator1 = pkgAppsList.iterator();
    while (iterator1.hasNext()) {

        ResolveInfo resolveInfo = iterator1.next();

        String[] buf = new String[] {
                resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, 
                resolveInfo.activityInfo.name};

        _activitiesBuffer.add(buf);

    } // while (iterator1.hasNext())

    _packages = new String[_activitiesBuffer.size()];
    _classes = new String[_activitiesBuffer.size()];

    Iterator<String[]> iterator2 = _activitiesBuffer.iterator();
    while (iterator2.hasNext()) {

        String[] buf = iterator2.next();

        // Store package information
        _packages[_index] = buf[0]; 

        // Store class information
        _classes[_index] = buf[1];

        _index++;

    } // while (iterator2.hasNext())

} // private void getAllInstalledActivities()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your system apps are stored with their unique package name that's why you are listing them with them. If you want only the last section of that name (supposing you have no duplicates) you can do some trick:

```
String s = "com.example.MyApp";
String appName = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(".")+1); // appName <- MyApp
```

Comment: I think it is not necessary that MyApp be the app name. I just browsed through the apps and package name and app name appear to be different. Could you tell what I can alter in the above code I posted?

Comment: Try `ResolveInfo resolveInfo = iterator1.next(); System.out.println("label = "+resolveInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()));` and look in your Logcat if loadLabel gives the string you wanted. If I've understood what you want, you need to get  <string name="app_name"> in `res/strings.xml` more than the package name retrievable throught package manager

Comment: No doesnt do anything. Still the same